# just allow user to enter in time format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have this in asp project:

[image]

Lenght is a decimal which calculated from start an finish time, now I change it to changing finish time according to Lenght input. so now I need to doesn't allow user to enter any thing out of this format hh:mm
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a mask for the input,In case you are able to use iMask and moment you could do something like this.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('test')
var momentFormat = 'HH:mm';
var momentMask = IMask(element, {
  mask: Date,
  pattern: momentFormat,
  lazy: false,
  min: new Date(1970, 0, 1),
  max: new Date(2030, 0, 1),

  format: function (date) {
    return moment(date).format(momentFormat);
  },
  parse: function (str) {
    return moment(str, momentFormat);
  },

  blocks: {
    HH: {
      mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
      from: 0,
      to: 23
    },
    mm: {
      mask: IMask.MaskedRange,
      from: 0,
      to: 59
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/imask/6.0.5/imask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```